# Avoid inserting duplicate column values

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple table with 3 columns `tag_id, label, timestamp` and I need as lightweight as possible a query to insert only when there is a new value for the column `label`.

How would I write an sql query to do this? I can see some examples already on the site but they are all mixed up in more complex queries (some involving subqueries) that I can't understand.

There seems to be different ways of doing it and I need to find out the most lightweight one so that I can repeat it in a loop to insert multiple tags in one go without putting too much strain on the server.

Comment: is the `label` a unique field?

Comment: label is just a char at the moment - should I set it as unique somewhere then? :)

Comment: you mean a string? just google for `mysql unique`

Comment: oh wow, so I just set a unique constraint to the column? wow ok..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD UNIQUE KEY (label);
```

This will enforce a unique value for that column in the schema.  You will get an error when you attempt to insert a duplicate value.  If you want to simply ignore the error, you can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO`.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use:

```
INSERT INTO table(`label`) VALUES ("new value") 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `label` = "new value";
```

Comment: This suggestion doesn't make any sense.